# Python 2.7 CSV file read/write \xef\xbb\xbf code

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, file-writing, file-read

I have a question about Python 2.7 read/write csv file with '`utf-8-sig`' code, my csv . header is

```
['\xef\xbb\xbfID;timestamp;CustomerID;Email']
```

there have some code(`"\xef\xbb\xbfID"`) I read from file `A.csv` and I want write the same code and header to file `B.csv`

My print log is shows:

```
['\xef\xbb\xbfID;timestamp;CustomerID;Email']
```

But the actual output file header it looks like

```
ÔªøID;timestamp
```

[image]

Here is the code:

```
def remove_gdpr_info_from_csv(file_path, file_name, temp_folder, original_header):
    new_temp_folder = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    new_temp_file = new_temp_folder + "/" + file_name
    # Blanked new file
    with open(new_temp_file, 'wb') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=";")
        print original_header
        writer.writerow(original_header)
        # File from SFTP
        with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:
            reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")
            first_row = next(reader)
            email = first_row.index('Email')
            contract_detractor1 = first_row.index('Contact Detractor (Q21)')
            contract_detractor2 = first_row.index('Contact Detractor (Q20)')
            contract_detractor3 = first_row.index('Contact Detractor (Q43)')
            contract_detractor4 = first_row.index('Contact Detractor(Q26)')
            contract_detractor5 = first_row.index('Contact Detractor(Q27)')
            contract_detractor6 = first_row.index('Contact Detractor(Q44)')
            indexes = []
            for column_name in header_list:
                ind = first_row.index(column_name)
                indexes.append(ind)

            for row in reader:
                output_row = []
                for ind in indexes:
                    data = row[ind]
                    if ind == email:
                        data = ''
                    elif ind == contract_detractor1:
                        data = ''
                    elif ind == contract_detractor2:
                        data = ''
                    elif ind == contract_detractor3:
                        data = ''
                    elif ind == contract_detractor4:
                        data = ''
                    elif ind == contract_detractor5:
                        data = ''
                    elif ind == contract_detractor6:
                        data = ''
                    output_row.append(data)
                writer.writerow(output_row)
    s3core.upload_files(SPARKY_S3, DESTINATION_PATH, new_temp_file)
    shutil.rmtree(temp_folder)
    shutil.rmtree(new_temp_folder)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`'\xef\xbb\xbf'` is the UTF8 encoded version of the unicode ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE U+FEFF. It is often used as a Byte Order Mark at the beginning of unicode text files:

- when you have 3 bytes: `'\xef\xbb\xbf'`, then the file is utf8 encoded
- when you have 2 bytes: `'\xff\xfe'`, then the file is in utf16 little endian
- when you have 2 bytes: `'\xfe\xff'`, then the file is in utf16 big endian

The `'utf-8-sig'` encoding explicitely asks for writing this BOM at the beginning of the file

To process it automatically at read time of a csv file in Python 2, you can use the codecs module:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(codecs.EncodedFile(infile, 'utf-8', 'utf-8-sig'), delimiter=";")
```

`EncodedFile` will wrap the original file object by decoding it in `utf8-sig`, actually skipping the BOM and re-encoding it in `utf8` with no BOM.

Comment: Hi Serge, thank you for the suggestion, I tried, it's still the same problem. I  was wondering if this the problem is because writer.writerow(original_header), the original_header is a list.

Comment: By the way if there have \xef\xbb\xbf\xef\xbb\xbf which code this is?

Comment: @SharpLu: If you have twice the utf8 BOM, then the file has been erroneously encoded twice in utf8-sig.

Comment: Thank you , the problem is fixed.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, looks like the arguments in `EncodedFile` are reversed. Should it be like this? `codecs.EncodedFile(infile, 'utf-8', 'utf-8-sig')`?

Comment: I agree with @VladSpreys. The arguments are reversed!

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the `EncodedFile` method from the `codecs` library as in Serge Ballesta's answer.

However using Python 2.7 the encoding `utf-8-sig` is not a supported alias for the UTF8-sig encoding, you need to use `utf_8_sig`. Additionally the order of the method properties needs to define the output data encoding first, and the file encoding second: `codecs.EncodedFile(file,datacodec,filecodec=None,errors=’strict')`

Here's the full result:

```
import codecs
with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(codecs.EncodedFile(infile, 'utf8', 'utf_8_sig'), delimiter=";")
```